# Why Schnorr was added to secp256k1 library instead of a separate library?

Tags: taproot, secp256k1, schnorr-signatures

[Schnorr signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) are often compared as superior to the Elliptic Curve ones. Then why developers [added](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/commit/4e43520026f5bcd182d21f0759bac159ef47bb62) Schnorr  into `libsecp256k1` library which is, as the name suggests, an *Elliptic Curve* library?

Why not create a separate C library? Or is Schnorr signature part of Elliptic Curve signature group?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the BIP340 signature scheme that was added to libsecp256k1 is an Elliptic Curve based variant of Schnorr signatures. Traditionally Schnorr signatures use a group of integer multiplication modulo a large prime, but that's not what is used here. It's integrated into libsecp256k1, because it is a Schnorr scheme over the secp256k1 group, so lots of code is shared between ECDSA and Schnorr.

Comment: Do all the advantages of Schnorr still hold even if it uses a non-traditional Elliptic Curve implementation?

Comment: "Schnorr signatures" isn't a fully specified scheme; it's a general class of digital signature algorithms with many possible variations. All the advantages of the BIP340 scheme over ECDSA obviously apply - the scheme was specifically designed to have those!

Comment: @PieterWuille whats the advantages of doing that over secp256k1 instead of the regular large prime"?

Comment: @Ron You mean using Schnorr over an integer multiplication group? That has all the disadvantages such groups have: you need around 3000-bit keys and signatures for a similar security level, they're much slower, and they need a very different security assuption than the one Bitcoin already relies on (secp256k1's DL hardness).